# How to use hybrid graphics Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) and Radeon R7 m260

Tags: 16.04, drivers, hybrid

I have a new Hp ZBook 14 G2, and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 lts on it. It has hybrid graphics with Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) and Radeon R7 m260, but I don't know how to switch between them.

I previously tried by using the official AMD graphics drivers, but the installation went wrong and when restarting the workstation, Ubuntu couldn't load my session.

Comment: @George can you please let me know how this [reject and edit](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/662448) is better than the suggested one? Thanks for any insights!!

Comment: @SouravGhosh, you left out __heavy programs - part of his OP__. That part I believe can determine the kind of advice he would be given as regards his issue.